# In Javascript How can I customize alert window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

In a static html page i want to do following actions:

1. as the url is entered first I want to display the terms and conditions using `window.alert("TERMS AND CONDITIONS")`.
2. In the dialogue box I want two buttons "agree" and "dont agree". If agree is pressed I want to  use `window.location.assign("next page url")` .And if dis agree is pressed I want to use `window.close`("","_self")

I'm a total beginner and have minimum knowledge of Javascript.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use some library for modal boxes instead.

Comment: try https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal

Comment: http://bootboxjs.com/

Comment: You can override the default alert with `window.alert = function (msg) { console.log('now alert goes to log: ', msg); }`. So, you will need to build your own alert popup from scratch

Comment: @ChenKinnrot When I use your code from the downloaded folder it works perfectly,  When I copy those codes in new file and  press Open model  it just adds #ex1 to the url.

Comment: @ChenKinnrot I see your code works completely and your model is attractive. But  I am having problem in even understanding everything you already mention. Would you please answer it so that I can understand it clearly and also accept the answer. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can not modifiy the default alert dialog.

But instead, you can use one of the many Dialogs made for jquery and other libraries.

http://www.sitepoint.com/14-jquery-modal-dialog-boxes/

Comment: You can not modify the default alert dialog, but you can override it to do something else.

Answer (score 1):

The alert box is a system object, and not subject to CSS. The jQuery UI Modal box does a lot of the work for you [Link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Answer (score 1):

if you want a basic browser graphic u can use

```
window.confirm("TERM AND CONDITIONS");
```

that return true or false based on action. For more advaced usage check jquery dialogs boxes (docs https://jqueryui.com/dialog/ ) or bootstrap (docs http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/)